# Константная ссылка на аллокатор в конструкторе std::vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, конструктор

Для чего в конструкторах std::vector принимается необязательный аргумент - **константная ссылка на аллокатор**? И бывают ли ситуации в которых это необходимо? Пробовал гуглить - ответа нет (или я неправильно гуглю). На cppreference пояснение есть только для копирующего конструктора, но не по моему вопросу: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector
[image: скриншот с cppreference]
[image: скриншот с cppreference]

Comment: Что такое аллокатор вам понятно?

Comment: Да, но я не понимаю смысла передачи константной ссылки на него, ведь по ней есть доступ только к max_size() и address(). С какой целью? Чтобы сделать копию?

Comment: Ага. У стандартного аллокатора никаких полей нет, поэтому для него это в принципе не нужно, но у какого-нибудь кастомного аллокатора они могут быть.

Comment: Я подозревал что-то подобное, но не был до конца уверен и ожидал какого-то подвоха. То есть получается, что это для универсальности. Спасибо за помощь)